# How to run Keywords directly instead of TestCases In robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I came across a scenario where i just want to create Employee details and not assert, is there a way in Robot framework where i can run a file which has ***KeyWords*** section and not ***TestCases*** and still execute the operation?

Comment: In a test case you don't need to have an assertion. Is there a particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: I want to create  suite which does my creation of employees, id's for employees etc.these operations mainly to reduce my manual effort of creating employee everytime to set my testing environment.Mainly keywords which executes these.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Suite Setup functionality?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t execute keyword without testcase.

Comment: Actually you can: in `*** Tasks ***` section.

Comment: Yes, just checked robot framework user guide, **Tasks** section is added in robot framework 3.1, and generally identical to **Testcase** syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is [robotlab](https://github.com/robots-from-jupyter/robotlab) which is a robotframework flavoured jupyterlab ide.

Teatcases and keywords are organised in so called notebooks. There was a lightning talk at the robocon conference last week, where they demonstrated execution of keywords without a wrapped test case.

Maybe that ide fits your need.